# ksqlDB can't get data from Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

Case: I have topic in Kafka with name `some_table_prefix.table_name`. Data is serialized with AVRO, but for historical reasons I have record in Schema Registry named `table_name-value`.

When I'm trying to setup ksqlDB stream

```
CREATE STREAM some_stream_name
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='some_table_prefix.table_name', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

I'm getting error `Schema for message values on topic some_table_prefix.table_name does not exist in the Schema Registry.Subject: some_table_prefix.table_name-value`.

I have Schema registry integrated correctly, for others topics everything works ok.

So, is it possible to specify Schema Registry record name in ksqlDB stream creation or resolve this issue some other way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a topic named `table_name`, that has Avro being produced to it (which would automatically create `table_name-value` in the Registry), then that's what ksqlDB should consume from. If you'd manually created that subject by posting the schema on your own, without matching the topic name, then that's part of the problem.

As the error says, it's looking for a specific subject in the Registry based on the topic you've provided. To my knowledge, its not possible to use another subject name, so the workaround is to POST the old subject's schemas into the new one